# PHP - how to sort an array of arrays in PHP using its key?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Basically, I just want to sort an array that looks like this:

```
    $a[] = array("id"=>'1', "name"=>'A', "text"=>'person a');
    $a[] = array("id"=>'2', "name"=>'B', "text"=>'person B');
    $a[] = array("id"=>'3', "name"=>'B', "text"=>'person B 2');
    $a[] = array("id"=>'8', "name"=>'A', "text"=>'person A 2');
    $a[] = array("id"=>'4', "name"=>'C', "text"=>'person C');
    $a[] = array("id"=>'6', "name"=>'B', "text"=>'person B 3');
```

I'm trying to sort it by name first and then id and should look like this:

[image: sorted]

I understand that `ksort` can sort according to keys as described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp). But the example is just a simple associative array.

Comment: why is it downvoted? is it because of the image or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function you can provide a user defined comparison function:

```
<?php
$data = [
    ["id"=>'1', "name"=>'A', "text"=>'person a'],
    ["id"=>'2', "name"=>'B', "text"=>'person B'],
    ["id"=>'3', "name"=>'B', "text"=>'person B 2'],
    ["id"=>'8', "name"=>'A', "text"=>'person A 2'],
    ["id"=>'4', "name"=>'C', "text"=>'person C'],
    ["id"=>'6', "name"=>'B', "text"=>'person B 3']
];
usort($data, function($e1, $e2) {
    return ($e1['name']==$e2['name']) ?
        $e1['id'] > $e2['id'] :
        $e1['name'] > $e2['name'];
});
var_dump($data);
```

The output obviously is:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["text"]=>
    string(8) "person a"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["text"]=>
    string(10) "person A 2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "B"
    ["text"]=>
    string(8) "person B"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "B"
    ["text"]=>
    string(10) "person B 2"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "B"
    ["text"]=>
    string(10) "person B 3"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "C"
    ["text"]=>
    string(8) "person C"
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not sorting by id after sorting by name though.

Comment: id sorted descending

Comment: thanks for your feedback, how to make it sort by id ascending after sorting by name?

Comment: @mantequilla The output was identical with the one you asked for in your question, `id`'s ascending. But indeed that was coincidence, since the input array was sorted that way. I modified the comparison such that both keys are considered.